# How to make Django user specific (data) in a to do app?

Tags: django

I am trying to separate tasks between all users that log in, but nothing I've tried has worked. All users are able to see other users' tasks, which isn't what I want. Below is the model and view function that I am using to create a task. Thanks in advance.

I believe the error might be in the view, since when I check the admin panel, each task is being created, but the user who made it isn't being set as the creator of the task for some reason. Any way I can change that?

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finish = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['complete']
```

Task View

```
def taskList(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''
    tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(title__contains=q,user=request.user)
    tasks_count = tasks.count()
    context = {'tasks':tasks, 'tasks_count':tasks_count}

    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)
```

Am I missing something in my models?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Maybe check if `request.user` is `None`?

Comment: how can I check if it is None?

Comment: For example, add this at the beginning of taskList function: `if request.user == None:` `return HttpResponse("ERROR: User is None")`

Comment: I tried what you said, but nothing printed out. It's weird, because in the admin panel, when I go to a task that a user made, the user's name isn't attached to the task. It's blank. So I think that this might be the error but I've no idea how to go about fixing it